# Amazon EC2 instance hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a application hosted in amazon EC2 instance. My application runs at http://ec2...compute-1.amazonaws.com/index.html. We also have a domain registered as sovan.test.com. WE want to use Route53 for redirect/open http://ec2...compute URL when user used the registered domain name. How can we do this?

We are getting an error that we can not host anything with index as back. and also it do not detect http:.

Please give some advice.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some more information? It is a bit unclear of what you are asking. Do you mean you need to assign the domain to that address? In that case you need to set up virtual hosts and point your domain to the public IP address of your instance... if you are running apache2 on your server here is more info: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Route53 is a Domain Name Service, which can resolve names into IP addresses. For example, if a user types www.foo.com, it can return the IP address of a web server of load balancer that will respond to a request.

Note that is only resolves the **domain**, which is the initial part of an address. It does not resolve the path portion of a URL. For example, going to `www.foo.com/index.html` will result in resolving `www.foo.com` to an IP address, then sending a request for the `index.html` page to that server. The `index.html` portion is not part of the DNS resolution.